# Is there a way to monitor all table/view updates under a dataset in BigQuery (GCP)?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I want to track all table/view updates in a separate tracking table i.e table created timestamp, table modified timestamp etc using stored procedure or Cloud Function or Python? I don't want to use Dataflow or Pub/Sub. Any pointers?

DATASET 1:

```
    |CREATED| MODIFIED |ROWS ADDED |ROWS DELETED|
```

Comment: What particular GCP product is hosting your dataset? BigQuery? Also please include the code or things you've tried thus far.

Comment: Most of the time, when you want to have track change, you want to track the event that perform this change (or to recieve as event the result of this change). In both cases, the event middleware on Google Cloud is PubSub. If you don't want to use it, I haven't solution!! And why you don't want it?

Comment: @ Daniel Ocando - Yes its BigQuery. No idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a table for logging. You could do this through [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#logs).

Audit logs record the following:

> - Administrative activity, such as creating or modifying resources.
> - Data access, such as reading user-provided data from a resource.
> - System events that are generated by Google systems, rather than by    user actions.

Once you have the logs, you can [export them to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery).